# EF Select MAX value that is <= 5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I can not figure out how using EF to select a DB row, based on its maximum value but which is lower or equals 5.

Here is my code, but this will select only a value, and not entire row:

```
Prices pr = db.Prices.Where(s => s.numdays <= totaldays).Max(s=>s.numdays)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. You want rows for which numdays is less than totaldays and numdays for same field? or less than max numdays for table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
Price p = db.Prices
    .Where(p => p.numdays <= totaldays)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.numdays)
    .First()
```